# saving xml data into AS3 variable / onComplete

Tags: xml, variables, actionscript-3, actionscript

im new to AS3. Looking to save data that i've loaded from an xml file into a variable. then call that variable later on.

heres my code:

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.net.URLVariables;

public class myClass extends MovieClip {
        public static var objectOneTotal:int = 1;
        public static var objectOneCurrent:int = 1;


    public function myClass() {


        var myXML:XML;
        var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        myLoader.load(new URLRequest("beers.xml"));
        myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

            function processXML(event:Event):void {
            myXML = new XML(event.target.data);

            myClass.objectOneCurrent = int(myXML.current);
            myClass.objectOneTotal = int(myXML.total);

            trace(myClass.objectOneCurrent);
            trace(myClass.objectOneTotal);

            }

        trace(myClass.objectOneCurrent);
        trace(myClass.objectOneTotal);
        var objectOneStart:int = objectOne.x;
        objectOne.x = (objectOneCurrent / objectOneTotal)  * (finish.x - objectOneStart);

    }

}

}
```

What its doing: when i run it, looking at the traces, its tracing the objects initial values of "1" before its tracing the values  which are loaded from the xml. So i believe it is loading the data, but the program is only running the processXML function after the rest of the code. or something.

Im not really sure. but i need the last two traces to read the xml data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because AS3 is asyncronous, it will execute the entirety of the `MyClass` method before the XML is loaded. When the XML does load, the code defined in `processXML` is executed to handle it.

The solution to this is to make `processXML` handle set `object1.x`:

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;

    public class myClass extends MovieClip {
            public static var objectOneTotal:int = 1;
            public static var objectOneCurrent:int = 1;


        public function myClass() {
            var myXML:XML;
            var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            myLoader.load(new URLRequest("beers.xml"));
            myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

            // these will fire before the XML is loaded
            trace(myClass.objectOneCurrent);
            trace(myClass.objectOneTotal);


        }

        public function processXML(event:Event):void {
            myXML = new XML(event.target.data);

            myClass.objectOneCurrent = int(myXML.current);
            myClass.objectOneTotal = int(myXML.total);

            // these fire after the XML is loaded
            trace(myClass.objectOneCurrent);
            trace(myClass.objectOneTotal);

            var objectOneStart:int = objectOne.x;
            objectOne.x = (objectOneCurrent / objectOneTotal)  * (finish.x - objectOneStart);

        }
    }
}
```